# Adding <br/> on keyup

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```js
$("#texto").keyup(function(e){
      if(e.key === "Enter"){
          var texto = $("#texto").val();
          $("#texto").val(texto+"<br/><br/>");
      }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" id="texto" name="texto" rows="8" style="resize:none;" ></textarea>
```

But the thing is, it writes the `<br/>` like I want but he changes line before it is written, and I want to know if it's possible to do the opposite, changing line after the `<br/>` is written.

Comment: Use `html` function instead of `val`

Comment: you'd be better off processing this after the input is complete - you can just substitute all the newline characters for br, either on the server, or if you process it in JS to display elsewhere on the page. All you're doing here is creating a kind of bizarre race condition between your code and the user's typing speed. There's no need to do it in real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `keydown` event which happens before the actual insertion of the character, this way your `<br>` will be positioned before the real enter char.

```js
$("#texto").keydown(function(e){
      if(e.key === "Enter"){
          var texto = $("#texto").val();
          $("#texto").val(texto+"<br/><br/>");
      }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea type="text" id="texto" name="texto" rows="8" style="resize:none;" ></textarea>
```